# When do you know you need to allocate for a link list and struct

Tags: c

When Should I allocate memory and why is my struct seem wrong? How do I create nodes to a link list in a repeated fashion?

**Edit:**
`char s;` to `char *s;` in `struct Basket`
Added `display()`
`printf("%c \n", node->s);` to `printf("%s \n", node->s);`in `display()`
Deleted some repeated code for brifer display

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLEN 100

struct Basket {
    char *s;
    struct Basket *next;
}
/* 
creat_nodes(struct Basket *node) {
    struct Basket *newnode = (struct Basket*) malloc(sizeof(struct Basket));
    newnode = (struct String *) malloc(sizeof(struct String));
    newnode->s = (char *) malloc(MAXLEN);
    strcpy(newnode->s, "a character or string");
    //link next, EDGE CASE IF it is LAST NODE?
    // if (node->next == NULL) return
    // else newnode-next->node
}

show_strings(struct Basket *list) {
    struct String *pt; // WHY THIS ?
    pt = list // because always because list always point to the first;
    while(1) {
       if(pt == NULL) break;
       Printf(pt->s);
       pt = pt->next; // does 'pt->=next' work?
            }
        }
```

*/

```
void display(struct Basket *node)
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s \n", node->s);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
int main(){
    // DUMMY VERSION/Test Version of create_nodes()
    struct String *node;
    node = (struct Basket *) malloc (sizeof(struct Basket));
    node->s = (char *) malloc(100);
    strcpy(node->s, "Hello");
    node->next = NULL; // RIGHT TO LEFT

    struct String *node2;
    node2 = (struct Basket *) malloc (sizeof(struct Basket));
    node2->s = (char *) malloc(100);
    strcpy(node2 --> s, "World");
    node2->next = node;

    //creat_nodes(node);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You declared `s` as a `char` but use it as a `char *`. Choose one and use it all over.

Comment: What is your question exactly ? How to make the `create_nodes` function work so that it can add any node, regardless of how many were already added?

Comment: @Isac Yes, `create_node` is just simply to create a node from reading string(s) and then link to exsiting linked list(if there's one) or just create a first linked list. I didn't know how exactly to code it so I created a dummy version in the `main` function to test it out. Also I have a question that I need a pointer to keep track on the very first node in the linked list and update it everytime I created a new node.

Comment: this struct definition is missing the trailing semicolon `;`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc)  1) do not cast the returned value.  the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always  check (!=NULL)  to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some typos that you need to fix first:

- If you have a linked list of `Basket` the next pointer has to be of type `struct Basket *`:

  ```
  struct Basket {
      char *s; 
      struct String *next; //here needs to be struct Basket *
  };
  ```
- You have a list of strings so the `display` function must show them accordingly using `%s` instead of `%c`

  ```
  void display(struct Basket *node){
      while (node != NULL)
      {
          printf("%c", node->s); //<---------here
          node = node->next;
      }
  ```

As to the `creat_nodes` function, it must receive the head of the list, create a new node and link it to some existing node. I'll assume you want to link it to end:

```
//note that now the function also receives the string to be stored
void creat_nodes(struct Basket **node, const char* stringToStore) {
    struct Basket *newnode = (struct Basket *)malloc(sizeof(struct Basket)); //create the new node
    newnode->s = strdup(stringToStore); //story a copy of the string with strdup
    newnode->next = NULL; //set the next as null, because this will be the last node

    if (*node == NULL){ //if this is the first node is NULL there is no list
        *node = newnode; //so the first node will be the new node
        return;
    }

    struct Basket *current = *node; 

    //if there are nodes, navigate to the last one
    while (current->next != NULL){
        current = current->next;
    }

    current->next = newnode; //append the newnode as the next of the last one
}
```

This now can be called in `main` as many times as you want to add subsequent `Basket` nodes:

```
int main() {

    struct Basket *listhead = NULL; //create the list

    creat_nodes(&listhead, "a"); //add a node with "a"
    creat_nodes(&listhead, "b"); //add a node with "b"
    creat_nodes(&listhead, "c"); //add a node with "c"

    display(listhead);

    return 0;
}
```

Note how the `creat_nodes` function was called with `&listhead`. When the first list node is `NULL` we want to change it inside the `creat_nodes` function, but in order to do that we can't just pass the pointer itself otherwise it would be a copy from this pointer in `main`. Instead we pass its address so that the function can go to the referred location and change it.

[Take a look at the code running in onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/SyaeaszAb)

Sample run in CodeBlocks:

[image]

Comment: Yours is First in First Out right ? Was my last in first out? If I want to make that into function how do I call it? I create a `struct node` then `create_node(struct Basket *node)` ? I don't quite understand your final note on `char[100]`. I would like to read strings as input rather than single char.

Comment: `char[100]` and `char*` are both strings. They just are allocated differently. So are you asking on how to make the `create_node` function work ?

Comment: At `struct Basket *newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct Basket));` it says `error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct Basket'`. If I put `newnode->next = NULL` in a if statement would be better? Because it only points to NULL once since I assume I will not delete nodes.

Comment: @CrouchinCorner Is that an error you got ? Running where ? and what code ? If you are running on C++ you need to cast the `malloc` result with `(struct Basket *)`

Comment: @CrouchinCorner That is odd, because i ran it in codeblocks as well without any issues. Did you change everything that was pointed out ? You have the full changed code in the live sample i linked at the end. Try to use that code if you are unsure as to what you changed.

Comment: EDIT: It was because I put the function BEFORE the `struct Basket{}`. is there a major difference in FIFO and LIFO? I imagine the linked list would be always added to the front(as from right to left)like |s2|next|->|s1|next|-> |s|next| -> NULL. You point the new node's next to previous node. If I do it from left to right, wouldn't I need to point the previous node to the new node, and the new node to NULL ?

Comment: @CrouchinCorner Yes there is a difference in FIFO vs LIFO. But it has to do with the implementation itself. You can implement both functions to add/remove at the start and add/remove at the end. With those 4 functions you can use both FIFO and LIFO if you want. FIFO would be add at the end remove at the start, and LIFO would be add and remove at the start

Comment: could you give me some insight on reading strings with delimiter? I don't know how to do it in a repeated fashion. I edited my code completely to yours as well.

Comment: @CrouchinCorner "I edited my code completely to yours as well" - That is not the idea though. The question was useful to you and others as it was, now that is no longer true, also this last edit of yours invalidates my answer. Remember that someone reads a question to find an answer to it, which in this case just doesn't make any sense since you changed the question entirely. Instead you should revert the edit you made and open a new question for that, since it is indeed a new problem.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your time! I edit as much as I can back to my original code with some extra added

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first things first, you are allocating "Baskets" and trying to assign them as "Strings", this occurs in the first "Basket" creation.

Next, you are trying to assign a pointer to an array of chars to a singular character. Try using a pointer value in your structure. This occurs in all basket creations.

Also, you are then trying to cast a "Basket" to a "String" which are of different types.

You may also have too null-terminate the strings where they read "a", "b" and "c"

As far as i can see, the rest should be fine

Comment: So edit it a few but I am not quite understand what you mean? Could you be more precisely? If I change my `char *s` to `string *s` it doesn't work, how do I do string linked list? Do i need to create `char *s[]` ?Does my `create_note()` work?

Comment: It is looking far far better though, I will look again. char *s[] would be an array of pointers though, might not be what you are looking for. Remember that an array of chars is very similar to the string class but does not have a length or size field, nor any other values within the structure. It is a raw, byte by byte structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
node2->next = node;
```

Suggest

```
node1->next = node2; 
node2->next = NULL;`
```